# "Transform does not contain a definition for scale, and no accesible method, bla bla bla" Unity C#, any idea?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

And here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
            gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Gone", true);
        }
        if (gameObject.transform.Scale.x == 0) {
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("Stage1");
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("Stage2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: well ... it doesn't ^^ Please see [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) ... in general your first approach should always be to consult the API and then come here with a specific implementation issue

Answer (score 1):

The line :**if (gameObject.transform.Scale.x == 0)** is the issue,
transform.Scale does not exist. You want to use transform.localScale (for local scale) or transform.lossyScale (for the total scale of the transform including parent's).

Answer (score 1):

`Scale` doesn't exist as a property of a [Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) instance, but you can use [localScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) or [lossyScale](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html), depending of your needs. More informations about can be found in the linked documentation.